# Converting a possibly null Double value to a String without exponent

Tags: java

I am attempting to create a function that will output a Double as a String with the following requirements:

1. It will not show with exponents. I believe Double.toString(dblVal) or dblVal.toString() will take care of the exponent issue.
2. If the Double is null it will not error and will display as 'null'. I believe String.valueOf(dblVal) will take care of this automatically if the Double is null.

Here is what I have:

```
function doubleToString(Double dbl) {
    String strVal = null;
    if (dbl != null)
        strVal = String.valueOf(dbl);
    
    return strVal;
}
```

What would be the best way to achieve both requirements? I don't think String.valueOf will get rid of the exponent so should I not be using String.valueOf() and instead using dblVal.toString() and then just to a manual check before hand on whether it is null or not and if so make strVal null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "one" standard library method that does everything you need. The trickier part is "not showing exponents" - one way I can think of doing that is with the `BigDecimal` class. This covers both of your requirements:

```
String doubleToString(Double dbl) {
    if (dbl == null) return "null";
    else return BigDecimal.valueOf(dbl).toPlainString();
}
```

Example: `doubleToString(1234e-100)` returns `0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001234`

Comment: How can I make this so there is a thousands separator like a comma?

Answer (score 1):

I think the following code will satisfy your requirements:

```
public class Solution{
    public static void main(String []args) {
        
        Double dblValue1 =  null;
        System.out.println(doubleToString(dblValue1));
        
        Double dblValue2 =  Double.parseDouble("5.895E+07");
        System.out.println(doubleToString(dblValue2));
            
}

    private static String doubleToString(Double dblValue) {
               
        if (dblValue != null) return BigDecimal.valueOf(dbl).toPlainString();
        else return "null";
    }
}
```

Comment: Will the .2f limit the amount of decimals? I want the full amount of decimals.

Comment: Yes, it will. I will just update the answer so that you can have all decimals

Comment: In case, if you want fixed number of decimal place just put `String.format("%.2f", dblValue)` insted of `BigDecimal.valueOf(dbl).toPlainString()` .......... also replace **2** with  the desired number or decimal points

Answer (score 1):

Using Java 8 [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Optional.html):

```java
String doubleToString(Double dbl) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(dbl)
            .map(d -> BigDecimal.valueOf(d).toPlainString())
            .orElse("null");
}
```

Although I am not sure if this is the "best way" as you asked!